# Scope of questions for serverfault

Tags: discussion, questions

Are only questions about server administration allowed on the serverfault site? I have noticed a lot of desktop configuration or administration questions have been closed.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is [addressed in the Server Fault FAQ](https://serverfault.com/faq) and I don't think the accepted answer here is correct.

> Server Fault is for system administrators and IT professionals, people who manage or maintain computers in a professional capacity. If you are in charge of ...
>
> - servers
> - networks
> - many desktop PCs (other than your own)
>
> ... then you're in the right place to ask your question! Well, as long as the question is about your servers, your networks, or desktops you support, anyway.
>
> Please note that Server Fault is not for general computer troubleshooting questions; if you paid for that desktop hardware, and it's your personal workstation, it is unlikely that your question is appropriate for Server Fault.

Server stuff is generally appropriate. This is the best rule of thumb for non-server stuff: **if it's a desktop PC, and you paid your own money for that desktop PC, it's unlikely your question is a good fit for Server Fault.**

Comment: Well.. I asked my question because I have seen questions about Desktops being closed that clearly showed a professional application (i.e. support of other users in a commercial environment). This seems to be in contradiction to the faq especially the part you quoted. Why are those questions closed?

Comment: I don't know. Flag them for moderator attention whenever you see them.

Answer (score 3):

Yes. Desktop config/admin questions will be redirected to [superuser.com](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/the-stack-overflow-trilogy/). In 6-8 weeks.

Answer (score -1):

Hmmm..i have been noticing it and wondering..it makes sense to keep professionally supported desktop PCs, if the focus (as i infer from some of the answers above) is to be kept on Professional support. On the other hand if the focus is about Servers, it is ok to remove the desktop PCs and move them to superuser.com.. Perhaps we should have a community poll? Ofcourse, we might want to keep both as common foci...

Comment: This has been discussed ad nauseum by the community. We agree, this site is for people professionally supporting networks including servers, workstations, and the myriad of technical equipment that support typical business activities. The potential audience is considered when evaluating a question, not the particular questioner exclusively.  Please see the [FAQ](http://serverfault.com/faq) for a few additional details; and the [Comms Room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/127) or [Meta](http://meta.serverfault.com/questions/ask) for specific questions.