# Should the XAMPP tag be removed?

Tags: discussion, tags

Should the [xampp](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/xampp) tag be removed?

I can flag a question as off-topic with the following reason:

> Questions on Server Fault must be about managing information technology systems in a business environment. […] **Questions about […] development tools may be asked on Stack Overflow**.

The toolset `xampp` is a development tool and not meant for production use. In my opinion, problems regarding configuration, etc. should be asked at stackoverflow. We should not give the impression that serverfault is the appropriate place to ask about XAMPP by providing a tag.

Tag stats serverfault: 16 followers, 206 questions
Tag stats stackoverflow: 244 followers, 5.8k questions

*(The [rules don't mention development tools](https://serverfault.com/help/search?q=development).)*

Answer (score 8):

I find your argument compelling.  I'm inclined to think the tag should be removed, but first, all the questions on the tag should be Dealt With, one way or another.

Comment: `killall -9 xampp`

Comment: Just as with [tag:virtualbos] there are circumstances when [tag:xampp] might be applicable. They will though be very rare and almost certainly don't exist already.

Comment: @Iain Virtualbox is a virtualisation platform which is *usually* used for dev work (because Vagrant, and because it's utter pants).  XAMPP, on the other hand, is *specifically* intended to be a dev environment -- the subtitle on http://apachefriends.org/ says "XAMPP is the most popular PHP development environment".  It should therefore not be used in production, and questions about it either get closed "off topic - dev env" or "off topic - best practices".

Comment: Strange as this may seem I am well aware of what VirtualBox and XAMPP are. If though I was a Windows admin tasked with deploying XAMPP for a group of developers then the tag may be applicable. Like I said rare but possible. I'v even argued against our support of xampp users in the past http://meta.serverfault.com/questions/4087/why-was-this-xampp-question-closed-and-why-are-so-many-xampp-questions-being-clo/4089#4089

Comment: @lain, In my opinion you still should ask at stackoverflow in that case. Being the admin is not the criterion, but deploying a development tool. If one has trouble with the deployment technique, he/she should use a tag to reflect that instead of what you are deploying. For example `deployment`. I don't want to say that one cannot put `XAMPP` in the title, though.

Comment: *In my opinion you still should ask at stackoverflow in that case.* - in the case that you're a sysadmin deploying XAMPP to a group of devs? That kind of question is off topic at Stack Overflow and explicitly on topic here.

Comment: If others use XAMPP for production, where do they ask questions about it? Telling them their questions are off-topic here because they're doing something they shouldn't be doing is not only arrogant, it is also wrong: even if the decision to use XAMPP is within their control, it probably isn't going to be what their question is about.

Comment: @reinierpost if someone is using xampp in production then they are doing it wrong. It is not meant to be in production, it is an abomination to use it as such.

Comment: @reinierpost the "bad practice" off-topic close reason is, in part, specifically for cases where you're using something in a manner contrary to the label.  Do you think diy.stackexchange is going to answer construction questions involving a stale bread roll to hammer a nail?  Hell no.  They're first going to tell you to get a hammer.